# Issue recursing through function in scheme

Tags: scheme

So I have a program that is a spell checker. The functionality of the program is that it hashes a word in four different ways and puts those hash values in a list. You provide a dictionary of valid words and perform the same operation on every word in the dictionary. The end result will be that every word will have a unique list of hash values. I can then provide a word as an input and generate a list of hash values and compare that to every word in the dictionary to see if it is spelled correctly.

```
(define gen-checker
  (lambda  (hashfunctionlist dict)
      (lambda  (w)
        (cond ((null? dict) 'False)
              (else
                   (if (equal? (functions hashfunctionlist (car dict)) 
                       (functions hashfunctionlist w))
                          '(True)

                     (gen-checker hashfunctionlist (cdr dict) )
                     ))))))
```

This is my code to do this.
It takes 3 parameters, the hash function list, the word, and the list of words in the dictionary. The only issue I'm having is that its not recursing on the line (gen-checker hashfunctionlist (cdr dict) ). Its just saying `#<procedure:...`

What can I do to make this recurse through the function?

Comment: Looking at your definition, `gen-checker` is a procedure that takes two arguments and produces a procedure `(lambda (w) ...`, and you're passing it two arguments. Did you intend to pass `w` to the recursion?

Comment: On a side note, the Scheme booleans are `#f` and `#t`. There's no need to invent your own.

Comment: @molbdnilo On a side note, Scheme is Lisp. Lisp is a family of languages. Maybe you meant Common Lisp, but that seems unrelated here.

Comment: @paul `gen-checker` is a function generator, right? It returns new function `(lambda (w) ... `. That's the only thing it does.

Comment: If think you have one lambda too many; use either `(define (function vars ...))`  or `(define function (lambda (vars ...)))`.

Comment: Because Lisp is a family of languages, and the kinds of questions you want to see on SO generally needs to be about the specific language in use (i.e., questions about Lisp in general are not good SO material, generally), I am on the tip of my tongue to propose that the [lisp] tag be blacklisted entirely, so people can't use it for questions.